# Help System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager find a type in a non-referenced assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, compilation, embedded-resource, assembly-resolution, buildmanager

I'm trying to write a plug-in system where assemblies can be dropped in a folder that ASP.NET has no knowledge about. This plug-in system works fine for ASP.NET MVC based assemblies, but for old-school WebForm assemblies (where the `.aspx` files `Inherits` the `System.Web.UI.Page` derived classes) `System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager` is responsible for compiling the `.aspx` file into a dynamic assembly.

My problem is that the `BuildManager` knows nothing about the assemblies within my plug-in folder and it seems to be absolutely nothing I can do to help it. If I do:

```
BuildManager.GetType("PluginAssembly.DefinedType", true, true)
```

it throws. If I first get a reference to the `Type` and then try:

```
var instance = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(path, type);
```

it still throws, even though I've now passed in the specific `type` it needs to compile the `.aspx` file. Is there anything I can do to help `BuildManager` find the types it needs to compile the `.aspx` file?

**Update:**
I've come one step further, by looking into what `BuildManager.GetType()` actually does. By specifying the assembly the type is defined in (such as "PluginAssembly.DefinedType, PluginAssembly") and then hooking myself onto the `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event, I can now find the plug-in assembly and return it so BuildManager can successfully construct the type. This makes the following work with flying colors:

```
BuildManager.GetType("PluginAssembly.DefinedType, PluginAssembly", true, true)
```

However, this still fails:

```
var instance = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(path, type);
```

Even though the `.aspx` file now has the same assembly reference in its `Inherits` directive:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"              
         CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs"
         Inherits="PluginAssembly.DefinedType, PluginAssembly" %>
```

The error I receive is:

"Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'DefinedType' does not exist in the namespace 'PluginAssembly' (are you missing an assembly reference?)" with the following source output:

```
Line 205:
Line 206:    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGlobalScopeAttribute()]
Line 207:    public class plugins_pluginassembly_dll_index_aspx
                 : global::PluginAssembly.DefinedType,
                   System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState, 
                   System.Web.IHttpHandler {
Line 208:        
Line 209:        private static bool @__initialized;
```

It seems like what happens inside `BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath()` involves a certain `System.Web.Util.IWebObjectFactory` that it might be responsible for throwing this exception by not finding my assembly. I can implement this interface without any problems, but what does that help if I can't tell the `BuildManager` about it?

Comment: What's the problem with having to recycle your application when you add plug-ins?

Comment: Because it will require taking down the whole website just to refresh one plug-in. Also, it probably won't work in medium trust and is imho a really poor solution.

Comment: Note the answer you are looking for but have you tried MEF?
http://blogs.msdn.com/hammett/archive/2009/04/23/mef-and-asp-net-mvc-sample.aspx

Comment: Yes, I'm using MEF and it does absolutely nothing to help me compile an `.aspx` file embedded within an assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this with [Web Deployment Projects](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=711a2eef-b107-4784-9063-c978edc498cd&displayLang=en) [[1]](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=0AA30AE8-C73B-4BDD-BB1B-FE697256C459&displaylang=en) by pre-compiling the whole web application into two separate assemblies and then digging into the right assembly with `Assembly.GetTypes()` to instantiate the correct `Page` for the given HTTP request.

It puts more on the shoulders of the plug-in developers, but yields better performance with the added benefit of having all plug-ins completely verified by the ASP.NET compiler before they're executed in a (security sensitive and fragile) web context.

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways you can specify the assemblies used to compile a page :

- Calling BuildManager.AddReferencedAssembly (but I assume you already tried that one ?)
- Putting in the compiling page's virtual directory configuration a list of the required assemblies (in the system.web/compilation/assemblies section) and having these assemblies accessible in the appdomain (the framework seems to use Assembly.Load to find assemblies found in the config files).

Comment: `BuildManager.AddReferencedAssembly` throws with "This method can only be called during the application's pre-start initialization stage" and modifying web.config isn't a viable option as that requires the application to restart and the modules to be pre-known which isn't always the case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how `BuildManager` loads the types, but you could *try* using `AssemblyResolve` -  subscribe to the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event, and load the assembly yourself and return (yes, return) the `Assembly` instance (or `null` if you don't recognise it).

Not all such code uses approaches compatible with this, but it is worth a try.

Comment: I've already done that and it works for resolving the assembly when compiling the .aspx.cs file, but when the .aspx file is compiled it references `global::PluginAssembly.DefinedType` which doesn't provide any means to resolve any assembly as the BuildManager assumes the assembly already exists in the app domain.

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing a lazy loading framework for ASP.NET myself.
Your plug-ins can always use the `<@ Assembly>` directive in their pages to manually reference the assembly.